# Make javascript code simpler using for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am new to javascript so my question may seem primary. How can I make this code more simple and less repetitive using `for` loop:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3m0apwk/)

```
SortingPageAudio.prototype.cardAudios = function (cardNumber) {
    var page = tabs.page;
    var card1Audio = page.card1Audio;
    var card2Audio = page.card2Audio;
    var card3Audio = page.card3Audio;
    var card4Audio = page.card4Audio;
    var card5Audio = page.card5Audio;
    var card6Audio = page.card6Audio;

    var FRcard1Audio = card1Audio.replace("e_", "f_");
    var FRcard2Audio = card2Audio.replace("e_", "f_");
    var FRcard3Audio = card3Audio.replace("e_", "f_");
    var FRcard4Audio = card4Audio.replace("e_", "f_");
    var FRcard5Audio = card5Audio.replace("e_", "f_");
    var FRcard6Audio = card6Audio.replace("e_", "f_");

    playAudio.stopAudioPlaying();
    if (cardNumber == '0') {
        (router.getLanguage() == 'french' ? playAudio.playFiles(FRcard5Audio) : playAudio.playFiles(card5Audio));
    } else if (cardNumber == '1') {
        (router.getLanguage() == 'french' ? playAudio.playFiles(FRcard4Audio) : playAudio.playFiles(card4Audio));
    } else if (cardNumber == '2') {
        (router.getLanguage() == 'french' ? playAudio.playFiles(FRcard3Audio) : playAudio.playFiles(card3Audio));
    } else if (cardNumber == '3') {
        (router.getLanguage() == 'french' ? playAudio.playFiles(FRcard2Audio) : playAudio.playFiles(card2Audio));
    } else if (cardNumber == '4') {
        (router.getLanguage() == 'french' ? playAudio.playFiles(FRcard1Audio) : playAudio.playFiles(card1Audio));
    } else if (cardNumber == '5') {
        (router.getLanguage() == 'french' ? playAudio.playFiles(FRcard6Audio) : playAudio.playFiles(card6Audio));
    }
};
```

Comment: Please do not use Markdown to "work around" not being able to post just a link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272129/using-markdown-to-bypass-link-to-jsfiddle-error

Comment: The jsFiddle is useless in this case. The code snippet is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using `for` loop, you can simply create an object.

```
SortingPageAudio.prototype.cardAudios = function (cardNumber) {    
    var rel = {
        '0': [tabs.page.card5Audio.replace("e_", "f_"), tabs.page.card5Audio],
        '1': [tabs.page.card4Audio.replace("e_", "f_"), tabs.page.card4Audio],
        '2': [tabs.page.card3Audio.replace("e_", "f_"), tabs.page.card3Audio],
        '3': [tabs.page.card2Audio.replace("e_", "f_"), tabs.page.card2Audio],
        '4': [tabs.page.card1Audio.replace("e_", "f_"), tabs.page.card1Audio],
        '5': [tabs.page.card6Audio.replace("e_", "f_"), tabs.page.card6Audio]
    };
    playAudio.stopAudioPlaying();
    router.getLanguage() == 'french' ? playAudio.playFiles(rel[cardNumber][0]) : playAudio.playFiles(rel[cardNumber][1]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it :

```
SortingPageAudio.prototype.cardAudios = function (cardNumber) {
    var langs = {
        french:{},
        english:{}
    };
    var en = langs.english;
    var fr = langs.french;
    var audio;

    for(var i = 1, max = 6; i <= max; i += 1){
        audio = tabs.page['card' + i + 'Audio'];
        en['audio' + i] = audio;
        fr['audio' + i] = audio.replace('e_', 'f_');
    }

    playAudio.stopAudioPlaying();

    playAudio.playFiles(langs[router.getLanguage()]['audio' + ((5 - cardNumber) || 6)];
};
```

But maybe you should cache your variable `langs` (and everything in) out of the function, because it won't change.

And just keep the two final lines in your function.